# Filter by modifiedDate newer than yesterday

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this bit of code that aside from the attempt related to `modifiedDate`, it works fine.

```
const MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const now = new Date();
const yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);

function extractStudentIDsAndSectionToSheets(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
  const files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "stuff" and mimeType = "application/pdf" and modifiedDate > "' + yesterday + '" and trashed=false');

let allIDsAndCRNs = []
  //Iterate through each folder
  while(files.hasNext()){
    let file = files.next();
    let fileID = file.getId();

(...)
```

The aim is to filter the files that are newer than yesterday (24h) but I'm having trouble adding that condition. It works fine If I use specific data, but I want to add a daily trigger to the script, so that's why it shouldn't be a static data.

How can I do this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share the full script you are currently using

Comment: @Logan thank you for your interest. I was provided an answer that works, nevertheless, the script I'm using is based on this `https://yagisanatode.com/2020/06/13/google-apps-script-extract-specific-data-from-a-pdf-and-insert-it-into-a-google-sheet/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the date to yyyy-mm-dd see  [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

This how to change Date format see [doc](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates#:%7E:text=To%20make%20sure%20your%20date,const%20now%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B)

Try this:

```
const MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const now = new Date();
const yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);
const formatedDate = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, "GMT", 'yyyy-MM-dd');
function extractStudentIDsAndSectionToSheets() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
    const files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "stuff" and mimeType = "application/pdf" and modifiedDate > "' + formatedDate + '" and trashed=false');

    let allIDsAndCRNs = []
    //Iterate through each folder
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        let file = files.next();
        let fileID = file.getId();

        (...)
```